# Issue with Displaying header tag in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using twenty twelve theme on word press and have an issue using a  tag (or any other header tag); It makes all the text disappear within that specific div.

I can use  but want to know why this is happening.

If I change the span to a H2 outside of WP it works fine so there is some issue with word press i am assuming.

my code:

```
<style> 
 .productContainer {
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        width: 900px; 
        height: 325px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .productContainer a { 
        text-decoration: none; 
    }

    .productContainer:hover { 
        border-color: green; 
        opacity: .5; 
    }
    .productContainer a img, .productContainer a img p { 
        float: left; 
        display:block; 

    } 

    .productContainer a img { 
        height: 300px; 
        width: 300px; 
        margin-right: 15px; 
    } 

    .productContainer p { 
        width: 500px; 
    text-align: left;
        text-decoration-line: none; 
        color: #A1c6E3; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    }
  .productContainer span {
        font-size: 24px; 
    margin-bottom 60px; 
}


 </style>


<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/rapid-worker/'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/BowFrontDesk_pacificexpresscopy_zps7e8dc151.jpg'/>
        <span> Rapid Worker </span>    
        <p>The Rapid Worker range is a versatile, sturdy range that will ensure that all your office needs are met. With a large range of desks, storage options, tables and much more you will be sure to find a solution that meets and exceeds your needs. </p>
<p>We will ensure that your new office furniture will be with you as soon as possible with all our range being shipped from our store within 7 Days ! </p>
</a>
</div>

<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=975'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/Corner_work_station_zps644dc92c.jpg'/>
        <span> Rapid Span</span>    
        <p>The Rapid Span range is for the person who wants to modernize and innovate. With clean white tops and funky bases, you are sure to inspire creativity        and productivity with the Rapid Span range. The range also includes various accessories such as storage units, pedestals and tables. </p>

<p>We will ensure that your new office furniture will be with you as soon as possible with all our range being shipped from our store within 7 Days! </p>
    </a>
</div>


<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=971'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/corner_workstationcopy_zps1ff2c6b7.jpg'/>
        <span> Rapid Manager </span>    
        <p>The Rapid manager range is elegant, classy and high quality. It will ensure that people know who’s boss.  With Cherry Wood tops and Ironstone bases the      Rapid Manager range is for the discerning executive.</p>

<p>We will ensure that your new office furniture will be with you as soon as possible with all our range being shipped from our store within 7 Days! </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=978'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/chair_mesh_am100_zps582ba090.jpg'/>
        <span> Seating </span>    
        <p>Pacific Express’ Seating range is extensive! Whether you want one chair or a hundred we can assist. We stock a vast range of seating options ranging from operational (desk) chairs through to visitor and lounge seating. We also know that comfort is imperative and as such we offer a range of AFRDI approved chairs. </p>

<p>We will ensure that your new office furniture will be with you as soon as possible with all our range being shipped from our store within 7 Days! </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://goo.gl/M1nY2j'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/tamboor_cupboard_zps0e8c0f6c.jpg'/>
        <span> Steel Storage</span>    
        <p>Pacific Express’ offers a range of Steel storage units. All units are sturdy, long lasting, and cost effective.</p>
        <p>As per usual all items will be with you as soon as possible with all our range being shipped from our store within 7 Days!</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=982'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/Screen_zps64d2ea85.jpg'/>
        <span> Screens</span>    
        <p>Pacific Express’ offers a range of Screens.  These screens are either floor standing or attached to a desk.</p>
        <p>As per usual all items will be with you as soon as possible with all our range being shipped from our store within 7 Days!</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

the website page is http://pacificexpress.com.au/products/

thank you

James

Comment: Try fixing your CSS syntax error - you're missing a colon after `margin-bottom` on your `.productContainer span`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is a CSS issue - the h2 tag (and other header tags) is a block-level element and by default, clears floats. In your case, the span works because it doesn't clear floats, and falls inline next to the product image. But an h2 clears it - so technically the h2 and all the text under it are still there, they've just been pushed below the image and are being hidden by the height of the containing div.

You can fix this by adding this to your styles

```
.productContainer h2 { clear: none; }
```